# Using `fetch()` to display plain text in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

Using Javascript to display a string variable in an HTML page is easy:

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
text = "hello"
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

However I would like to replace "hello" with the contents of a local file, say `file.txt`. I think this should be easily accomplished using Javascript's `fetch()` API but I'm running into problems. This,

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
text = fetch('file.txt').then(response => response.text())
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

will display `[object Promise]`. I guess I somehow must access the `response` object but I don't know how that is done.

Comment: You need to wait till `fetch` completes. Try using `await` like this:                
`text = await fetch('file.txt').then(response => response.text())
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text`

Comment: @Nimad this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

`response.text()` returns also a promise. So you have to add another then to get the text.

```
response.text().then(function (text) {
  // do something with the text response 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`text` in your code is a promise, not text. You need to use the promise callback:

```
fetch('file.txt')
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.text();
})
.then(text => {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

Comment: Wait. There **has** to be a dupetarget for this. Right, marking CW and off to look...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're doing `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text` before the prmise has resolved and you have your text. Try doing

```
text = fetch('file.txt').then(response => {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = response.text()
})
```

Comment: This produces the same output as my original (non-working) code.